# How to hide Tomcat version from error messages when using embedded servers in Java

Tags: security, server, embedded-server

I have a java application where i'm using embedded Tomcat servers,
which looks like this

```
Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat()
```

I'm creating an embedded tomcat server here.

**Problem statement**

whenever there's an error it displays information on which tomcat version i'm using,
[image]

how to hide this in java?

i have a little idea that i need to override *ServerInfo.properties*, but how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how we can do this in java, but if you are using any build scripts like ant / gradle for distribution purpose, we can write a task to override / harden the jar file, and replace the **ServerInfo.properties** file with the customized value whatever we need.

the code for ant build scripts would look like

```
<target name="override.tomcat">
        <jar destfile="path/to/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar" update="true">
            <fileset dir="src/"> <!-- folder where you keep the directory/file to raplace-->
                <include name="org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties"/> <!-- file to replace within directory path in side the jar-->
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

and in gradle

```
task overRideTomcat(type: Jar) {
    from(zipTree(file("path/to/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar"))) {
        exclude '**/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties'
    }

    from('src/') {
        include('/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.properties')
    }

    archiveName "tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar"
}
```

make sure you have the modified ServerInfo.properties file under src directory in the same path as you have mentioned in the include statement.